# jqgrid with web api not getting populated

Tags: jqgrid

I am very new to jqGrid. I am trying to load simple jqgrid using asp.net web api.
The api send back the list of emailDto. The emailDto is plain class with 3 public properties

The problem is the jqgrid is not getting populated. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
function dataBindToGrid() {
        var lastsel;
        $("#emailgrid").jqGrid({
            url: '/api/email/',
            datatype: "json",
            mytype: 'GET',
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
            colNames: ['Address ID', 'Type', 'Email'],
            colModel: [{ name: 'Address_ID', width: 70, primaryKey: true, editable: false, sortable: false, hidden: false, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'Email_Type', width: 70, editable: true, align: 'left', sortable: false },
                    { name: 'Email_Address', width: 200, editable: true, align: 'left', sortable: false }

            ],
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                    var grid = $("#emailgrid");
                    grid.restoreRow(lastsel);
                    grid.editRow(id, true);
                    lastsel = id;
                }
            },
            //This event fires after all the data is loaded into the grid
            gridComplete: function () {
                //Get ids for all current rows
                var dataIds = $('#emailgrid').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                for (var i = 0; i < dataIds.length; i++) {
                    //Put row in edit state
                    $("#emailgrid").jqGrid('editRow', dataIds[i], false);
                }
            },
            rowNum: 3,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: "Email Addresses"
        });
    }
```

Comment: would you be able to post the code at the url /api/email/ that is receiving the request

Comment: yes. I did check it and it does get posted.

Answer (score 0):

When configured for jsondatatype, jqGrid expects data in the following json format:

```
{ 
  "total": "xxx", 
  "page": "yyy", 
  "records": "zzz",
  "rows" : [
    {"id" :"1", "cell" :["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
    {"id" :"2", "cell":["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
      ...
  ]
}
```

data returned must match this otherwise it will not work. This is the default json structure (you can change this if you want). Depending on what browser you are using, you should be able to see the ajax request and response with what data is being sent and returned when the grid is building itself (Firefox use firebug, IE use the developer toolbar)

as per [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Actually I don't need total, page and no of records. I am only allowing max 3 email addresses only.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Just added to jqGrid below and it works.

```
jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                page: function () { return 1; },
                root: function (obj) { return obj; },
                records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
            },
```